# use of java functions in grails 3.2.0

Tags: grails

Previously like grails 2.5.0 the java functions were written in util and can be use by importing the util package but in grails 3.2.0 how to use java functions it does not allow to use the util package like previous version of grails 2.5.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Previously like grails 2.5.0 the java functions were written in util
>   and can be use by importing the util package but in grails 3.2.0 how
>   to use java functions it does not allow to use the util package like
>   previous version of grails 2.5.0.

In 2.5.0 the recommended place to put those utility classes would have been `src/groovy/`.  In 3.2.0 the recommended place is `src/main/groovy`.

Comment: Thank You Jeff Scott Brown.